# Otimizar página de informativo

Tags: php

Tenho uma página que recebe informativos mensais, para exibir o mês desejado pelo usuário faço o seguinte:

```
<a href="?mes=ago2015" class="list-group-item 
<?=($mes=='ago2015')?'active':''?>" id="ago2015">Agosto / 2015</a>
```

E chama a página referente com um include:

```
$mes = empty($_GET['mes'])?'infos':$_GET['mes'];

case 'ago2015': 
    include('infos/agosto2015.php');
break;
```

Alguém sugere alguma forma melhor para tal?

Comment: Para cada mês de cada ano fazes isso?

Comment: @JorgeB. até um momento tem 3 meses, mas em tese seria, por isso quero mudar...

Comment: Bia as informações de cada mês estão numa base de dados?

Comment: @JorgeB. não, são páginas.

Comment: Então não estou a ver uma melhor forma de fazer isso. Deixa ver se alguém tem outra ideia.

Comment: Não vejo outro jeito também de fazer isso de maneira mais otimizada. Se estivesse numa base de dados era outra história, mas como não está, esse é um bom jeito de fazer.

Comment: @Zoom eu também gosto de Flash, mas mudando o foco... Essas páginas são feitas em HTML, na mão mesmo, se fizesse algo mais intuito como um cadastro de informativo e colocasse no banco, resolveria essa questão? Pois quanto mais informativo inserir, maior e "ruim" ficaria esse código.

Comment: Que Legal! O episódio ontem foi top. Então, com certeza essas informações numa base de dados seria melhor, por vários motivos. Teria uma melhor organização, manutenção, o código não ficaria extenso, não teriam muitas páginas **.html** tomando espaço no seu servidor. Dá um pouco de trabalho cadastrar tudo, mas vale a pena pensando na usabilidade do sistema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma de otimizar isso, seria criar um array as chaves são os meses e os valores os nomes dos arquivos para fazer o include. O ideal era guarda esses valores no banco.

```
<?php
    $informativos = [
                    'set/2015' => 'info/set2015',
                    'out/2015' => 'info/out2015',
                    'nov/2015' => 'info/nov2015',
                    'dez/2015' => 'info/dez2015',
                    'padrao'   => 'info/404.php'    
    ];


    $mes = empty($_GET['mes']) ? 'padrao' : $_GET['mes'];

    include_once $informativos[$mes] .'.php';
```